# How to align content inside UITableViewCell for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios8, xcode6.1

I have build a custom table cell:

[image]

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var streetLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    func loadItem(#street: String, city: String, price: String){
        self.streetLabel.text = street
        self.cityLabel.text = city
        self.priceLabel.text = price
    }
}
```

Result on iPhone 5:

[image]

Result on iPhone 6+

[image]

As you can see the left side of the cell is displayed correctly, it sticks to the left. However the right side should stick to right but it does not. So here is my question:

- How can the width of the cell be set to the width of the tableView so that the cell has the same width as the screen?
- How can I make the right side actually stick to the right of the table cell?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @CleverError yes I do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewCells are always the with of the UITableView they are in so there is noting that you need to do.

Based on the screenshot you posted, it doesn't look like you are currently using autolayout to position your labels. What you'll need to do is just add a constraint from the right of your price label to the right of the cell. Then when the cell grows, your label will keep the same distance from the right edge of the cell.

Your constraints for the top labels should then look like this.

[image]